# Jupyter uses wrong version of numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter, sys.path

I am trying to import `pandas` in a Jupyter notebook and having trouble because it's using an old version of `numpy`. I believe I've traced the issue to the fact that I have two versions installed:

**Version 1.8.0rcl** is in:
`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python`

**Version 1.13.3** is in:
`/Users/<username>/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages`

When I run the python interpreter from the command line, it imports the newer version, but when I run a jupyter notebook, it imports the older version. I've checked the `sys.path` using both methods, and they are the same. This further confuses me because in `sys.path` the directory for the newer version comes BEFORE the directory for the older version. Based on how I thought `sys.path` works, that would mean jupyter notebook should be importing `numpy` from the directory with the newer version in it.

I found another question where someone ended up just renaming the directory with the old version in it, but I'd rather not do that (and also am not sure I have permission to do that anyway).

Can anyone help explain what is going on here, and suggest some solutions?

Comment: Are you using environments? Check the kernel(s) jupyter is using with `jupyter kernelspec list`

Answer (score 1):

Please read [this long post](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/) from Jake Van der Plas describing how importing works and why you think Jupyter is using the wrong numpy.

Once you get how things works, you should be able to fix it following the instructions in Jake's post.